# Protocol/delegate in Swift3 doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have followed [this tutorial](http://blog.ericd.net/2016/10/03/protocoldelegates-in-swift-3-0/) to have delegate methods to update a value in my other class, but it does not even trigger it. Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
protocol myDelegate {
    func report(info:String)
}

class TypeFilterViewController: UIViewController, XLFormRowDescriptorViewController,
                                UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var delegate:myDelegate?

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         self.delegate?.report("testValue")
         self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true) 
    }
}
```

So, after i select the row item, i dismissed pushed view and display previous class.

```
class SearchRefinementsTypeCell: XLFormBaseCell, XLFormBaseCellSeparator, myDelegate {

    // Delegate method
    func report(info: String) {
        print("delegate: \(info)")
    }

    override func update() {
        super.update()
        let mc = TypeFilterViewController()
        mc.delegate = self

       self.headerLabel.text = //Value from TypeFilterViewController didSelectRow
    }
```

Thank you for all kind of helps.

Comment: Why would you ever need to delegate from controller to a cell, not vice versa? You're creating a new controller object in a cell class every time update() function is called and never use that object, it is just released when the function is finished

Comment: I am using Xlform library, so SearchRefinementsTypeCell is my customized cell in main view not in TypeFilterViewController, and TypeFilterViewController has hiw own another cell. These 2 is actually not related to each other. But somehow i need to update a label in this SearchRefinementsTypeCell after user select the cell under TypeFilterViewController and didSelectRow is triggered. I hope i could explain it.

Comment: Great answer by @alexburtnik I totally agree. The protocol should be a part of the custom cell class, and the view controller should conform to the protocol. You need to flip things around.

Comment: @umitk. So you have two view controllers, right? What do you actually want to do when cell is selected on `TypeFilterViewController`?

Comment: When cell is selected by now it dismisses TypeFilterViewController and triggers the update(). What i want to do is set the label inside update() to the value i selected in TypeFilterViewController.

Comment: @alexburtnik i updated the question.

Comment: @Umitk Check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You clearly misunderstood the tutorial.
Delegate pattern is useful when you want to delegate from a cell to view controller. You're doing the opposite: sending event from a viewController to a cell, which is pointless, since your viewController already has access to it's tableView, which in it's turn operates with it's cells.

Also you shouldn't use any `ViewController`s inside cell class because it breaks MVC pattern. You should think of `UITableViewCell` and pretty much every `UIView` as of powerless objects which cannot decide anything by themselves, but can only delegate events to other smart guys, which do the logic by themselves (view controllers).

Now about your case:
You have vc A and vc B, pushed over it. When a cell in B is pressed, you should send a callback to A, right? What you should do:

1. B has a delegate which implements some protocol
2. When A pushes B, it set's itself as a protocol: `b.delegate = self`
3. When a cell is selected in B, you call delegate's method, which is implemented in A and passes a string into it.
4. UI in A is updated.

Once again, cells must not know anything about any of your view controllers, they are just pawns. All logic should be handled between view controllers themselves.

Comment: I have done what you said but it does not trigger. Maybe this is kinda special case yeah, using xlform method, but there should still be a way to use protocols here. i dont know why.. i will upvote this anyway, and thanks for help.